# How can I check if I directory exists in a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a `docker cp` command in my script to copy a container directory to my host machine. In some cases the directory will not exist in docker, and I get "Error: No such container:path"

Is there a way to check if this directory exists in the container, and only perform `docker cp` if it does?

The reason for this is that not having this directory in the container is normal for some situations, so I'd like to avoid the error message.

To clarify: the source directory I want to copy doesn't exist *in the container*, so I cannot copy it. The destination directory exists.

The container is stopped, so `docker exec` doesn't work.

Comment: Why not run `mkdir -p` first followed by the `cp`?

Comment: @gtzkw just added clarification: it's the source directory that doesn't exist, not the destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution could be to execute the following command:

`docker exec container_id [ -d "/dir_path" ] && echo "Exists" || echo "Does not exist"`

Then you can determine the directory existence from the returned message.

Comment: That's a nice idea, unfortunately at this point of time the container is stopped, so I get "Container .... is not running"

Comment: Is starting it, just to checking if directory is there and then stop it is an option? If yes I can update my answer.

Comment: that's not perfect, but I guess that's the best I have at the moment. Thanks.